# How do I validate user input with c++?

Tags: c++

Hey so this is really getting on my nerves.

I'm trying to validate user input within a loop.

I need the user input to be between 0 and 60. I can validate it no problem but what I want it to do is re-ask the previous question if the input is incorrect, you know? like repeat the loop if that makes sense

```
int main()
{
    //Constants 
    const int MAXROUNDS = 4;
    const int NUMARCHERS = 3;

    //Variables
    int archerNum;
    int roundNum;
    double score;
    double total;

        //Start of outer loop, this loop displays each Archer 
        for (archerNum = 1; archerNum <= NUMARCHERS; archerNum++)
        {
            total = 0; //This clears the total for the archer 

            //Start of second loop, this loop displays each round
            for (roundNum = 1; roundNum <= MAXROUNDS; roundNum++)
            {
                cout << "Enter Round " << roundNum << " score for Archer "
                    << archerNum << ": ";
                cin >> score;

                if (score < 0 | score > 60)
                {
                    cout << "ERROR! Number must be between 0 and 60!";
                }
            }

            total = score + score + score + score; //This calculates the total score for the tournament 
            cout << "\nThe total score for archer " << archerNum << " is: "
                << total << "\n\n";
        }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code ^

Now I have tried so many things. I've looked through my textbook and I've googled everything but I cant seem to find the answer.

I've tried putting the error message in a do-while loop
i've used if-else statements 
i've used while loops
I think I've literally used every different type of loop there is and I still cant seem to figure it out and I'm becoming very frustrated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: " I've looked through my textbook " - I  guarantee your textbook has nothing like `score < 0 | score > 60` in it. Or if it does, get another textbook.

Comment: Recommend adding the missing includes and `using` statement for completeness.

Comment: The bug pointed out by Neil is often also pointed out by compiler warnings. The code in question is syntactically correct, so the compiler allows it, but it's so often a mistake that the compiler usually brings it to your attention. If you don't get a warning, turn up the warning level. In g++ I use `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. In Visual Studio don't go below /W3, and you probably want /W4. Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors, so turn them on and crank them up **LOUD**.

Comment: The tradition in C++, which it inherits from C, is **zero-based indexes**. That is: `for (int round = 0; round < MAXROUNDS; ++round)` Don't start at `1` if you can avoid it, it just confuses everything.

Comment: my teacher told me it was supposed to start at 1, and as for that first comment @NeilButterworth I meant I checked my textbook to figure out how to enter validations I didnt specifically check it for the score < 0 | score > 60

Comment: If the teacher wants origin 1 indexing, so be it. Give 'em what they want. But it often makes your job harder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply add `roundNum -= 1;` inside the validation If statement. It will make the counter decreased by 1, and re-ask the previous question

```
//Start of second loop, this loop displays each round
            for (roundNum = 1; roundNum <= MAXROUNDS; roundNum++)
            {
                std::cout << "Enter Round " << roundNum << " score for Archer "
                    << archerNum << ": ";
                std::cin >> score;

                if (score < 0 || score > 60)
                {
                    std::cout << "ERROR! Number must be between 0 and 60!"<<endl;
                    roundNum -= 1; //or roundNum--
                }
            }
```

Comment: You use `variable++` but not `variable--`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you damn I've been trying to figure out what I was missing for a while now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version of just the number input and error message:

```
//#include "pch.h" if using Visual Studio 2017
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 60." << endl;
  int input;
  cin >> input;
  while(input < 0 || input > 60 || cin.fail()){ //Using cin.fail() here in case the user enters a letter or word
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cerr << "Number must be between 0 and 60. Please try again." << endl;
    cin >> input;
  }
  return 0;
}`
```

Alternatively, you could use a `goto` statement though, as I am sure many others on this site will tell you, that is not recommended as it leads to the infamous 'spaghetti code'.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
bool inputError;
do {
    inputError = false;

    std::out << "Enter Round "
             << roundNum 
             << " score for Archer "
             << archerNum << ": ";
    if (std::cin >> score) {
        if (score < 0 || score > 60)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR! Number must be between 0 and 60!";
            inputError = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "ERROR! Your input must be a number";
        inputError = true;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    }
} while(inputError == true);
```

Comment: Missed the `|` vs. `||`.

Comment: I'd suggest rather than messing around with `bool inputError;` use of the `break` keyword would be in order.

Comment: @EdGrimm The OP does not seem very I good. I am looking at this as a training for a junior Engineer. This is how you would implement it as a beginner. Once you understand the basics of what is happening we can optimize or simplify or adjust with a break. But at this point that seems like jumping a bit far ahead.

Comment: I guess I learned programming in a different order, because break was covered pretty early on, and I never learned to test to see if boolean variables were true by comparing them to true. As a general rule, I really don't want to teach new programmers through writing code that I'd never want to see in a production program, if I could at all help it. Right before I learned break, I was shown a `bool var=true; while (var) { ... if (success condition) { var=false; } }`, which I wouldn't have objected to.  Needlessly twiddling inputError each time through though?

Comment: I will agree with @EdGrimm , break is covered earlier than comparing bool statement which is more readable for beginner

Comment: @EdGrimm In programming the very first control structure anybody learns is `if statement`.This is the simplest building block. The next is `loop statements` as these are built on top of `if statements` (A loop is an an implied if goto). Next would be `switch like statements`. It is not until **after** these you learn about `break/continue/return statements` as these are complex changes in the control flow. Maybe if you had taught programming at a University you might have seen that. I challenge you to pick up any introductory book on programming and look at the order of concepts it teaches.

Comment: @gameon67 I don't think so. Boolean tests are the most fundamental part of programming. While break is a complex flow control concept that can not really be understood until after you understand simple if statements which are then the basis for loops. breaks come ofter loops.

Comment: @MartinYork it depends on your teacher.  I was taught break along with the rest of loop statements.  Switch statements came significantly later.  This was, admittedly, back in ye ancient times, in the days when teachers actually explicitly taught their students to not compare booleans to true or false, because they were fundamentally conditional results themselves, so you either just use the boolean variable or not the boolean varaible in most cases.  On rare instances, you might compare a boolean variable to another boolean variable.  Never to constants.

Comment: @EdGrimm Your thoughts on teaching are fundamentally flawed. You are assuming the student already knows how to program and you are teaching them the best way. That is not how teaching is done. You have to build up the skills from the bottom up. Then mean you have to teach them basics and show comparisons. Then when they actually understand all the concepts you can then pare away some of the excess and explain why certain things are unnecessary.

Comment: @EdGrimm Looking at your flawed answer above that you are definitely not following best practice guidelines. Never re-use variables for two different purposes (this kind of micro optimization is best left to the compiler). Also you are not actually validating the input at all. Come pick your game up.